# Android counter part to iOS' URLSessionTaskMetrics

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, networking, nsurlsession

Like the title says, in iOS 10 Apple released [URLSessionTaskMetrics](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontaskmetrics), a class that allows developers see detail information about each network request. Is there any Android library that allows developers to see such a granularity for each request?

Comment: I think the [Android Profiler Tool for Network](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/network-profiler) is going to help you out.

Comment: @ReneFerrari that tool is actually part of the Android Studio. What I am looking for is a library that I can implement as a part of the app and show some statistics on a dashboard-like view.

Comment: Ah I see. Sorry I thought just tracking for App analysis purposes is sufficent. Do you want to track all the requests which are made by the device?

Comment: @ReneFerrari for example, if I make a call to my API layer, I want to see all the hops that the call makes, or perhaps redirects that are being made, trace the path of that call